# C program: how to find the maximum/minimum frequency of a character in a string

Tags: c, string, character, frequency

I am trying to find a way to get the values of max/min freq of characters in a string

E.g. helpme

would have max freq = 2 and min freq = 1
(there are 2 e's and there are other letters that occurs once)

another E.g. aaaa

would have max freq = 4 and min freq = 4

I am trying to program this, but I don't know what to do after I receive the string by using scanf.

Assume that there are only lowercase and there are no space between words.

Additionally, I prefer more of a brute force search over an elegant solution that consists of type casting and whatnot. Just started to use C, so simple as possible please. BTW, I don't mind if it's just an advice or a basic procedure of how to do this. I don't necessarily need the whole code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to build a histogram:

```
size_t histogram[UCHAR_MAX] = { 0 };     // allocate and initialise histogram

for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)    // generate histogram for string s
{
    histogram[(unsigned int)s[i]]++;
}
```

After this you can just do a linear scan through the histogram looking for the min and max letter frequencies.

Comment: If `s` is a `char*` then be careful, `char` might be signed.

Comment: True - I was going to keep quiet about that - I suppose I'll have to add a messy cast... ;-)

Comment: Of course, nobody said this was performance-critical in any way, but still ... it's scary to see `strlen()` used like this, since it turns a linear-time algoritm quadratic.

Comment: @unwind: yes, it's always a tough call when writing example code for a beginner as to the trade-off between simplicity and best practices. In theory though the compiler could optimise the call to strlen out of the loop, I believe. I've taken out the strlen now.